# Save a matrix in QSettings

Tags: c++, qt

I'm working on my  qt chess game, in particular on persistence, so when the MainWindow is closed I have to save the int matrix, which represents the board state. I already wrote the function and it's working well with a matrix that I give for the test

```
MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    int boardState2[8][8] = { {-5, -3, -4, -9,  0, -4, -3, -5},
                              {-1,  0,  0, -1,  0, -1, -1, -1},
                              { 0,  0,  0,  0, -1, -2,  0,  0},
                              { 0,  0, -1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0},
                              { 0, -1,  0,  1,  1,  4,  0,  0},
                              { 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0},
                              { 1,  1,  1,  0,  0,  1,  1,  1},
                              { 5,  3,  0,  9,  2,  4,  3,  5} };
   
    session.setBoardState(boardState2);
}
```

This code is in the "MainWindow.cpp" file, I will not show the setBoardState function cause it works as I said, instead the problem is that I should copy the real matrix in this boardState2, in order to store it in the settings file using that setBoardState function. The problem is that the real matrix is in another file "Piece.cpp" and it's a global int matrix. I don't know how to pass it from "Piece.cpp" to "MainWindow.cpp"... I was thinking to 3 solutions:

1. Pass the matrix from one .cpp to the other through some functions that I don't know
2. Call the `session.setBoardState()` function in the Piece destructor, but the problem here is that I have to use the class Session (which has the QSettings) as a singleton. I already tried this but I have problems with the Session constructor
3. Save the real matrix in a .txt file and then read it from the MainWindow.cpp

If you need more informations I will edit this post, hope you can help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The c++ keyword **extern** can help you. Using **extern** you can use the global matrix which is defined in other cpp file.